# How to get rid off Mysql has gone away error permanently

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have recently switched from mysql_ to PDO and it has been real pain. Everything seems so complicated.

In the past I developed a system where a user imports the csv containing records. These rows are then imported into database through a while loop. It worked perfectly on `mysql_query` . But on PDO whenever I try to import more than 3k rows it always gives error Mysql has gone away and the process breaks in between.

This is a real problem as I have file containing more than 600k rows. I Googled a lot and there were so many different solutions to problems. I have tried these but to no avail. I have set persistent connection to false.  Here is the code which connects to MYSQL:

```
public function __construct($driver_options=null) {

    try {
        parent::__construct('mysql:host='.Database::DB_HOST.';port='.Database::DB_PORT.';dbname='.Database::DB_NAME,
                            Database::DB_USER, Database::DB_PASS,$driver_options);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10000000000); // to show error
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // to show error
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); // defend sql injection
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);   // defend sql injection

    } catch(PDOException $e){                
        die('Uncaught exception: '. $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

So is there any permanent solution to this problem? Or should I just switch back to `mysql_`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [mysql data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load serious data from a csv.

It's super quick (like seriously stupidly super quick compared to inserts) the syntax is simple to use and you can do just about anything you want with it - if you are loading from a CSV it should certainly do all you want.

A simple code example (pinched from the docs) looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

This loads the data.txt file into a table called `tbl_name`. It writes that the fields are terminated by a comma (normal CSV stuff) and each field is enclosed in a double quote - and that the lines use a return feed and new line as a break. It also says to ignore the first line (which probably has headers in it) and go from there.

Comment: Unfortunately the admin is non-tech person and he wants to import csv through the front end admin panel. That's why I created the interface.

Comment: @AhmarAli Just upload the file to the DB server and run the command. You can still use a front end admin panel.

Comment: The admin wants to import the csv himself so how can I allow him to do that through frontend using load data infile?

Comment: @AhmarAli Upload the file from the user to a spot on the server, use the `load data` command on that file, wait till it has finished, then delete the file all in the same script. :)